# Scraping Calendar data problem with next day date

Tags: python, date, screen-scraping, icalendar

Good morning, I have a problem that I do not know how to solve, through web-scraping I take data from the website where I work and create a ics calendar file with my shifts, it works almost always well, only when I have a shift that ends at midnight or later I get an error, this is because in the page I find only the start date and not the end date, so if I finish at 00.00 the correct date should be the next day, but it is added the same as the beginning so I get an error, do you have any idea how to correct this error?

"python nameerror free variable referenced before assignment in enclosing scope"

```
            # CLEANING DATETIME DATUM
            datclnd = soup_datum.replace('.', ' ')
            dated = tempo.datetime.strptime(datclnd, "%d %m %Y")
            yearclnd = dated.year
            monthclnd = dated.month
            dayclnd = dated.day
            # CLEANING DATETIME DATUM
            # CLEANING DATETIME HOUR AND MINUTES
            time_split = soup_dienstbegin.split(":")
            dienstBH = int(time_split[0])
            dienstBM = int(time_split[1])
            #dienstende
            time_split2 = soup_dienstende.split(":")
            dienstEH = int(time_split2[0])
            try:
                dienstEM = int(time_split2[1])
            except:
                NOTHING
            def ics_working():
                event = Event()
                event['uid'] = f'19970610T172345Z-AF23B2@{dayclnd}{monthclnd}{yearclnd}'
                event.add('summary', f'{string1}{tagesinfo2} {soup_kommentar2} {kursinfo}')
                event.add('description', f'{schiffinfo}Schichtdauer: {soup_schichtdauer}, Bezahlte Zeit: {soup_bezahltezeit}\n, Infos: {schiffinfo}')
                event.add('dtstart', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd,dienstBH,dienstBM,0))
                event.add('dtend', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd,dienstEH,dienstEM,0))
                event.add('dtstamp', datetime(yearclnd,monthclnd,dayclnd,dienstBH,dienstBM,0))
                organizer = vCalAddress(f'MAILTO:{receiver_email}')
                organizer.params['cn'] = vText(f'{username} Monatsplan')
                organizer.params['role'] = vText(f'{username} Monatsplan')
                event['organizer'] = organizer
                event['location'] = vText('Werftestrasse 5, 6002 Luzern')
                # Adding events to calendar
                cal.add_component(event)
                # Printing working day info
                print(f'Datum: {soup_datum} Dienst: {string1}{tagesinfo2} --> Mannschaft: {crew_list2} --> OK')
            ics_working()
```

Comment: If the shift end time is less than the shift start time, add a day to the shift end date.

Comment: Yes, I know but I don't know how to do it, as I only extract one date on the page, I should assign that if the end date is 00.00 it should go to the next day, but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: [How to add Days to a Date in Python?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-python/)